# How to set a shell variable in a Singularity definition file so that it is seen by several sections

Tags: singularity-container

I need to set a version string for an app that I am packaging in a Singularity container. This version string is used in several places in the definition file (`*.def`).

I know that I can set a shell variable in the `%post` section like this:

```
%post
...
VERSION="x.y"
cp /path/$VERSION /otherpath
...
```

but these settings are valid only within the `%post` section (which actually makes sense).

I also know that I can define environment variables in the `%environment` section but these settings are only when the container is **run** and will not be "seen" during image build time.

What I would like to have is a mechanism whereby I could say `VERSION="x.y"` somewhere in the definition file and then I could refer to its contents as `$VERSION` in several sections, e.g. in `%post` and then in `%test`, `%labels` etc.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the `%arguments` section, introduced in [Apptainer 1.2](https://apptainer.org/docs/user/1.2/definition_files.html#arguments). Works similarly to the [Dockerfile ARG keyword](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) in that the value defined under `%arguments` can be overridden by setting the `--build-arg` command line argument when executing `apptainer build`.

In my use case, the definition file would look like this:

```
%arguments
  VERSION=x.y
...
%post
  ...
  cp /path/{{ VERSION }} /otherpath
  ...
%labels
  Author Joe Bloggs
  Version {{ VERSION }}
...
```

If you use Singularity, the feature is available since [Version 4.0CE](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/4.0/user-guide/definition_files.html#default-variable-values-the-arguments-section).

**NOTE** that the `%arguments` section is not supported in earlier Apptainer or Singularity versions.